# Android App compiled on AOSP can't be installed in lower sdk-version emulator

Tags: android, apk

I downloaded the newest source code of Android form git,
and I managed to compile the source code and made a SDK and a emulator with the verison AOSP.

Then I tried to modified the source code of LatinIME the input-method and managed to compile and run on the emulator compiled along with the code of version AOSP.

Then I want to install the apk to my phone whose sdk-version is 2.2, and the error appeared to say my sdk-version is too low.

I'm sure I've add the `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` in the `manifest` node in `AndroidManifest.xml` , but it still needs the AOSP version to install.

Is that means I will have to repo the 2.2 version source code to compile the apk so it can fit my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm answering my own question again, I can't understand why my questions always rarely answered.

However I searched the whole Internet and can find a answer, but in luck I saw this:

[version_defaults.mk of API Key 7](http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/build/core/version_defaults.mk?r=4)

I simply replaced the android/build/core/version_defaults.mk in my downloaded code tree and re-compiled the module, and it worked!

Thought I don't know if it will work all modules in the source code, but however my IME works good.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you added in the manifest the min sdk version? I don't think you have added features compatible only for froyo or newer.

The original manifest http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=it#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/AndroidManifest.xml&q=latinime&d=2

deos not have a min sdk version. Try to remove it.

Comment: It is because the original one can not be installed so I tried to add this line. Both is not working.. I just can't find in the code where restricts the sdk version, but when installing it just needs the AOSP version.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do this with android > 7 :
put `LOCAL_MIN_SDK_VERSION := 25` в Android.mk (your app module)